# Checking if a point is inside negative box

Tags: python

I have made this little function for checking if a point is inside a selection box:

```
def select(x1, y1, w, h):
    x, y = position
    x2 = x1 + w
    y2 = y1 + h

    if x >= x1 and y >= y1:
        if x <= x2 and y <= y2:
            selected = True
    else:
        selected = False
```

But it only works if w and h are larger values than x1, and y1. For example, it doesn't work if the box has a negative size. How can I include checking those cases without a prior check of `if w < x1 and h < y1`?

Comment: To clarify, it doesn't work if w and h are positive, but smaller than x1 and y1?

Comment: @HankDitton Yes that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the minimum and maximum of the two numbers, and assign them to variables in one statement, using `sorted(list)` and destructuring assignment. Also note the use of `min <= value <= max` chained comparisons:

```
def select(x1, y1, w, h):
    x, y = position

    minX, maxX = sorted([x1, x1 + w])
    minY, maxY = sorted([y1, y1 + h])

    if minX <= x <= maxX and minY <= y <= maxY:
        selected = True
    else:
        selected = False
```

Comment: I did not know python could do this, nice looking solution and educational!

Answer (score 2):

Why not using the following checks:

```
if x >= min(x1,x2) and x <= max(x1,x2):
    if y >= min(y1,y2) and y <= max(y1,y2):
        ...
```

Comment: or `if min(x1,x2) <= x <= max(x1,x2):`

Comment: Because it does not provide the deselection?